# Loop issue, script not adding the correct members to groups

Tags: powershell, scripting

Ok so code first:

```
 import-module activedirectory

. "C:\Users\ben\Documents\Get-Directreport.ps1"

$ou = "ou=test, ou=Litmos, ou=Resources, ou=Groups, ou=company, dc=domain, dc=net"

$creds = "domain.net\ben"
$server = "dc01.domain.net"

$managers = get-adGroupMember -identity "CN=All Managers,OU=Organizational,OU=Groups,OU=company,DC=domain,DC=net" | select name, samaccountname
$name = $managers.name

$ReportsTo = Get-adgroup -searchbase $ou -filter "Name -like 'Report to *'" | where {$_.name -replace 'Report to ' -in $name} | select name, samaccountname
$Reports = $reportsto.name

$underlings = Get-Directreport $name | select samaccountname

Foreach ($manager in $name) { 
    if ($manager -notin ($reports -replace 'Report to ')) 
    { new-adgroup -name "Report to $manager" -groupscope global -path $ou }
 }   
 

ForEach ($report in $reports) {
    #Get-Directreport $name | select samaccountname
    {add-adgroupmember -identity $report -members $underlings.samaccountname}
}
```

So this script is creating the 'Report to $name' groups correctly, and it's adding members however all 300 groups that this creates has the same set of members. I've tried putting the $underlings line inside the last loop but that resulted in no members at all.  I'm pretty sure that line is the culprit but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

EDITS

First off apologies for the stuff I left out originally. I guess that's what I get for being in a hurry at the end of the day.  In any event, so this code is trying to create a series of new AD security groups, namely the "Report to x" mentions. It creates those folders by iterating over the members of teh "All Managers" group and the X variable will be each ALL Manager members name values.
Then I'm trying to populate those groups with the corresponding users. Which is where it's failing.
The line for `Get-Directreport $name | select samaccountname` Does in fact return what it should. I can run that entire line include $underlings in the terminal and it returns correctly.
I agree with Colyn1337 in that it's that line.. I'm unsure how to get it to iterate.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This comment contains critical feedback and your answer.  For readability, continue pipe operations on the next line.  Long one liners might get you kudos in syseng, but not in dev.  Check into splatting as well.  Both these things make your code easier to read.  The next big thing, is your post doesn't include a clearly defined statement of what this code is trying to achieve forcing the reader to infer it.  As such, I can't fix your code.  Having said that, your problem is with '$Underlings'.  It's not being iterated over so it has the same object array.

Comment: Does `Get-Directreport $name | select samaccountname` return what you expect for any `$name` value that you test?

Comment: I made the changes as per Colyns comment, sorry for that :). AdminOfThings, yes it does! Returns exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some time working through the script I've offered some changes and and inline comments.  Please have a look

```
import-module activedirectory

. "C:\Users\ben\Documents\Get-Directreport.ps1"

$ou = "ou=test, ou=Litmos, ou=Resources, ou=Groups, ou=company, dc=domain, dc=net"

$creds = "domain.net\ben"
$server = "dc01.domain.net"

$managers = get-adGroupMember -identity "CN=All Managers,OU=Organizational,OU=Groups,OU=company,DC=domain,DC=net" | 
    Select-Object name, samaccountname

# remove this and just use $managers.name.  No need to create this.  
## $name = $managers.name 

# Groups where name like "reports to $managersName"
$ReportsTo = Get-adgroup -searchbase $ou -filter "Name -like 'Report to *'" | 
    Where-Object { $_.name -replace 'Report to ' -in $name } | 
    Select-Object name, samaccountname

# Same as before.  No need for $Reports array.  Just use $ReportsTo.Name were needed
## $Reports = $reportsto.name  # AD Group names like "reports to <manager>'   


# list of  users for all managers?  Does Get-Directreport take an array of managers or does it expect only 1 manager?
# If sending multiple managers does work, which it sounds like it doesn't, but if it did you would have an array of all direct reports 
# for all managers in $name.  This should probably be moved into the foreach ($manager in $name) loop
## $underlings = Get-Directreport $name | Select-Object samaccountname  

Foreach ($manager in ($managers.Name))) { 
    # Creates  missing "Report to <manager>" groups
    if ($manager -notin (($ReportsTo.Name) -replace 'Report to ')) { 
        new-adgroup -name "Report to $manager" -groupscope global -path $ou 
    }

    # Get managers direct reports
    $underlings = Get-Directreports $manager | Select-Object samaccountname

    # Get manager's "report to <manager> group again to update memebers"
    $managerReportToGroup = Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $ou -Filter "Name -like 'Report to $manager'"
    if ($managerReportToGroup) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $managerReportToGroup.Name -members $underlings.samaccountname
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Could not locate group for $manager"
    }

}   

# For each "reports to $managerName" group, adding direct reports found from Get-Directreports function/script
# $reports will not have any newly added groups from previous loop.  Would need to call Get-AdGroup again
# Recommend moving loop up into $manager loop
## ForEach ($report in $reports) {
##     #Get-Directreport $name | select samaccountname
##     { add-adgroupmember -identity $report -members $underlings.samaccountname }
## }
```

Comment: Very, very close.  So *Get-DirectReport "sameaccountname" | select Samaccountname* returns a list of the direct reports attribute in AD.  I think that'd be an array but to tell the truth I'm not smart enough to know a list or an array, right now.
The code above does generate a set of errors, namely it throws a fit the the Reprot To group already exists.  But more than that calling the Get-Directreport function is not working properly. I'm going to try pasting it's entire code into a function block to see if that helps. I'm prolly doing the Dot source all wrong.

Comment: Actually got it working with BIG help from you https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel I did have to make a coulpe super small changes.  Namely removing the 3rd ) in $managers.Name))) and changed the $managers def removing *| name* leaving only *samaccountname*.  After that she runs!! Thank you so much.